# Angular 2: Display Search Results in Another Component

Tags: angular, search, methods, angular2-components, angular-template

My search field is on a separate component. There is no problem in displaying the names on the suggestion list when searching because I'm not displaying them in different component.

> Search HTML

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search" (keyup)="getSuggestion($event.target.value)">
<div class="suggestion" *ngIf="results.length > 0 && suggest === true">
     <div *ngFor="let result of results" class="search-res" (click)="showEmployee(result._id)"> {{ result.name }} </div>
</div>
<div class="suggestion" *ngIf="results.length === 0 && suggest === true">
     <div> No results found </div>
</div>
```

> Search Component

```
getSuggestion(name) {
    $('.suggestion').show();
    this.searchService
        .getSuggestion(name)
        .subscribe(
            name => this.results = name,
            error => alert(error),
        );
  }
```

But how about if I want to display it in another component (list component) on `change` event?

**What should I add in the input field as function call? and what should I put in SearchComponent such that the results would show in List Component?**

> SearchService

```
getSuggestion(name:string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http
        .get(this.serverUrl + 'name/' + name)
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Have a Subject in your SearchService. Having subject, you dont need to tell other component that a new result has come. As soon as there is a result , the view automatically updates.

```
private results = new BehaviorSubject([]);

public getResults$(){
   return this.results.asObservable();
}

public search(params){
   //do search and add results to 'results'
   this.results.next(response);
}
```

In your List component

```
constructor(private searchService: SearchService){
   searchService.getResults$()
                 .subscribe(res){
                     this.results = res;
                  };
}
```

In your HTML

```
<div *ngIf="results.length>0" >
   <!-- show results -->
</div>
```

---

Exact code for your case :

**Search Component HTML**

```
<input type="text" 
       placeholder="Search" 
       (keyup)="getSuggestion($event.target.value)">
```

**Search Component ts**

```
public getSuggestion(name){
    this.searchService.getSuggestion(name);
}
```

**Search Service**

```
private results = new BehaviorSubject([]);

public getResults$(){
   return results.asObservable();
}

public getSuggestion(name:string) {
    this.http
    .get(this.serverUrl + 'name/' + name)
    .map(this.extractData)
    .subscribe(
        response => this.results.next(response),
        this.handleError
    );
}
```

**List Component ts** 
    public results = null;

```
constructor(private searchService: SearchService){
    serachService.getResults$()
                 .subscribe(resultList: any[] => {
                      this.results = resultList;
                  });
}
```

**List Component HTML**

```
<div class="suggestion" 
     *ngIf="results && results.length > 0 ">
     <div *ngFor="let result of results"
           class="search-res" 
           (click)="showEmployee(result._id)"
      > {{ result.name }} </div>
</div>
<div class="suggestion" 
     *ngIf="results && results.length === 0 && suggest === true">
     <div> No results found </div>
</div>
```

By setting results to null, we will know if there was a search call made. If results is not null but empty, we will know search results is empty.

Comment: In SearchService, do I need to create that public search(params)? @Skeptor

Comment: Yes, that is where you do the search logic. From SearchComponent you will call it . In your case it is `getSuggestion`

Comment: I've appended the `getSuggestion` code from SearchService. Thank you so much @Skeptor

Comment: I did not test the code. so let me know if gives any error or not functional

Comment: There is an error when I leave the search field empty after searching @Skeptor

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147776/discussion-between-char-and-skeptor).

Comment: I got it to work following the code snippets. The key concept that I didn't get at first was that the `results` array in the _ListComponent_ gets _linked_ in the constructor to the `results` in the SearchService which is of type `BehaviourSubject`. This is an observable and the result items will be added to it with the `next` method. +1